# To find the norm of a linear functional $f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\displaystyle{f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)}$ for all $x\in C[-1,1]$. I want to show that $f$ is continuous and calculate its norm.

I have tested the continuity as follows:

Let $x\in C[-1,1]$ such that $\left\|x\right\|\leq 1\Longrightarrow\displaystyle{ \max_{t\in[-1,1]}|x(t)|\leq  1}$
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)|&=&\left|\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)\right|\\
&\leq&\left|\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)\right|\\
&\leq&\int_{-1}^{1}\left|x(t)\right|dt+\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\left|x(k/n)\right|\\
&\leq&\left\|x\right\|\int_{-1}^{1}dt+\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\left\|x\right\|\\
&=&2\left\|x\right\|+\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}\left\|x\right\|\\
&=&3\left\|x\right\|
\end{eqnarray}

I need to find the norm. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bound is tight.  To find an $x$ that almost achieves the bound, you might take $x$ that is $-1$ at each of the points $k/n$ but $+1$ except in small intervals around those points.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle{f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)}\quad  \textrm{for all}\quad  x\in C[-1,1]$$ taking $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ both sides we get,  $$\displaystyle{f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)}\\\implies\displaystyle{f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}.\frac{2}{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}x(k/n)}\\ \implies \displaystyle{f(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt $$ See if this does help.

Comment: Who said anything about a limit? $n$ is a fixed positive integer in the question.

Comment: oh! but that is not mentioned